# Agora Cloud Recording not recording the publisher (Host in the live streaming)

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I'm using agora cloud recording to record the live stream. It's working fine for all the users except the host(publisher). The call is connected and the all users can listen to each other in live call mode, but when I got the recorded file from the stop method, I couldn't listen myself(host or pubsliher)

Here is the code that I'm using in the start method `

```html
  const data = {
          cname: me.props.channel,
          uid: USER_ID.toString(),
          clientRequest: {
            token: me.state.token,
            recordingConfig: {
              videoStreamType: 0,
              maxIdleTime: 30,
              streamTypes: 2,
              audioProfile: 1,
              channelType: 0,
            },
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem in the Payload of Start API,
You have missed these Params in the PayLoad

**"subscribeVideoUids": [subscribeVideoUids],

"subscribeAudioUids": [subscribeAudioUids],**

in the both params you have to passed host uID and then your stop api will works fine.

Comment: These are optional params and I didn't set them out because by default agora will consider all the users in the channels and so It does but only problem is with the host.